# CMake: What is the advantage of using -D (command line) over add_compile_definitions or target_compile_definitions or set?

Tags: cmake

New to CMake. When adding libraries I see a lot of instructions saying do this:

```
cmake -D OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=/usr/local/opt/openssl
```

Why is that preferred over putting it in the actual CMakeLists.txt? *e.g.*

```
set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR "/usr/local/opt/openssl")
```

Comment: With the second option you limit reuseablility. You hardcode a path into the project that may not be correct on a different machine without providing any means of overriding the value. I'd expect the FindOpenSSL module to look into default locations, so the second option hardcodes machine-specific details into the project. If you're providing a reasonable default here, use `set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR "/usr/..." CACHE PATH "....")` which allows for overriding via explicitly specified command line variable or via setting a standard variable before `add_subdirectory`ing your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You do not commit the first one to the repository while you either commit the second one or have to be careful to not commit it with other stuff.
- The second method is usually used to allow users of some project to modify some aspect of that project. So whatever pertains to the project itself (not customizable) goes straight to the CMake files everything else might be provided from the command line.

Note, also, that the [CMake presets](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html) add an ability to customize the build outside the CMake files so the method of providing variables directly via a console call is something I'd expect going away and getting replaced with presets. But the way they work is still the same: variables defined in the preset get to CMake cache with generated console call (with an IDE it might be different).

Comment: Ah, so is that because `/usr/local/opt/openssl` won't be where it is for everyone, so making it a command-line arg forces people to supply their own locations?

Comment: @slackwing yes, full paths to things shouldn't be kept in the repository unless they are stable full paths for everyone. It also not necessary forces anything. For example, if you have your openssl library in some usual place (which might be the case for many Linux users) you don't need to provide anything at all and a Windows user might provide the necessary variables during the build, leaving the CMake file clean and working for both categories.

Comment: @slackwing probably the `FindOpenSSL` module looks at the default installation location for the given platform. If my assumption is correct, you do not need to provide the value at all assuming the openssl installation you want to use is the one in the standard location...

Comment: @fabian yeah, every module uses default paths because it is a property of `find_path`/`find_library`.